# how to know machine name and program name in postgresql?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, pgadmin, aws-sct

```
select secure_decrypt_log_id_seq.nextval,**v.PROGRAM**, 
'CONTRACT_PAYMENT_ID = '||to_Char(:new.CONTRACT_PAYMENT_ID), sysdate, user, **v.MACHINE**, ls_transaction_type
from v$session v
where v.sid =  (select sid from **v$mystat** where rownum = 1)
```

I am not able to find equivalent functions in PostgreSQL. The above code is of oracle and I cannot find any proper references to Program, Machine & mystat. AWS-SCT cannot find similar functions in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

You can have the client address: `client_addr` in [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) (or `client_hostname` if you have enabled `log_hostname`).

There is no way to access the name of the client executable on the server, as such information is not reliable, but my recommendation is that the client sets the [`application_name`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-APPLICATION-NAME) parameter and the server fetches it from `pg_stat_activity`.